# Enable Cookies In Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, cookies

I used session to pass data from page to page and works before, but now when I call the data by using a variable from other pages, the variable is empty (""). I read an article about cookies being disabled.

[ASP.NET Session is not keeping stored across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230777/asp-net-session-is-not-keeping-stored-across-pages)

How do I then enable it?

Regards

Comment: Keep in mind that Internet Explorer has a thing for underscore character in virtual path and will reset session vars if ur path has it '_'. Another thing is to set session state to in proc, google it. And cookies to 'on' all in web.config of ur website

Comment: Check out this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the below link in this  we are going to check if a cookie exist, and if it does, add data to it, and then read from that
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r36h9N66vT4